# Using the jquery-terminal emulator widget without jquery

Tags: jquery-terminal

Is there a way to use this terminal widget without jquery. I mostly use vanilla js on my site, and I want to include this terminal.

1. Is it possible to use without jquery?
2. Is there a good alternative?
3. If not, what is the least intrusive way to use this on an existing page that doesn't use jquery? (without actually using iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use it without jQuery but there is one different library that can work with vanillaJS, which is [terminalJS](http://www.erikosterberg.com/terminaljs/).

There is also [xtermjs](https://xtermjs.org/) but that one is more for apps that emulate real terminal (it supports curses apps like vi or tmux) and in most cases using websockets.

Comment: Is jquery a hard core dependancy or can it be removed after some work ?

Comment: @solsTiCe it's very tightly coupled, but it's probably doable to removed it, you will need to replace all DOM manipulation, size calculation and jquery plugins usage with functions calls. Nothing is impossible if you have time. Maybe replacing jQuery with its own small DOM library for start that use jQuery and then create DOM library that use modern browses API. I can think about this.